# php slim code not working giving error?

Tags: php, rest, slim

I have written the code in the php slim which is giving only error in spite of giving the right data to the code here is the code :-

```
$app->post('/login',function(Request $req,Response $res){
    if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('phone','pin')))
    {
        $requestedBody=$req->getParsedBody();
        $phone=$requestedBody['phone'];
        $pin=$requestedBody['pin'];
        $db=new dboperation();
        $responseData=array();
        /*$result=$db->userLogin($phone,$pin);*/

        if($db->userLogin($phone,$pin))
        {
            $responseData['error']=false;
            $responseData['User']=$db->getUserbyphone($phone);
        }
        else
        {
             $responseData['error']=true;
             $responseData['Message']='Error:Please try again';

        }
      $res->getBody()->write(json_encode($responseData));    
    }
```

Here is the login method :

```
function userLogin($phone,$pin)
 {
     $pass=md5($pin);
     $stmt=$this->con->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_phone=? AND user_pin=?");
     $stmt->bind_param("ss",$phone,$pass);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->store_result();
     return $stmt->num_rows>0;

 }
```

Even I have tried using $result but I am unable to get the result could anybody tell me where I have gone wrong and how could I correct it ?

Comment: Show userLogin method.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone please see the edited code and tell me where i could go wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no error the result is coming false

Comment: got the error since md5 encryption is creating problem and i'm removing it for intial time but please suggest me good options for encrypting the pin as it is pruely digits